# Update single value by point at it, without mutation and reconstructing object's initial structure JS

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a way to better organize my actions/reducers, now it looks like this:

```
[SOME_ACTION]: state => ({
    ...state,
    isModified: true,
    orders: {
        ...state.orders
        // or maybe change something here
    },
    documentation: {
        ... state.documentation
       // or maybe change something here
    }
})
```

The problem is that the object has deep nesting, and I have to keep track  of every level of it and add it everywhere accordingly. And I have to write all of that just to update **a single** value.

What are my options? For now I just want to be able to update one/several values on some level of nesting by just point on what I want to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have to copy the object that changes and its parent objects, not its child objects. For instance, in your example I assume the change is `isModified: true`. You don't need to copy `orders` or `documentation`, you can reuse them because they haven't changed:

```
[SOME_ACTION]: state => ({
    ...state,
    isModified: true
})
```

You can give yourself a utility function to do changes if you like. For instance:

```
function newState(state, path, value) {
    const result = {...state};
    const lastKey = path[path.length - 1];
    let obj = state;
    for (const key of path.slice(0, path.length - 1)) {
        obj = obj[key];
    }
    obj[lastKey] = value;
    return result;
}
```

...or similar (that's off the cuff).

In that specific case it's not all that useful since the change is shallow:

```
[SOME_ACTION]: state => newState(state, ["isModified"], true)
```

But if you had a change to make deeper in the structure:

```
[SOME_ACTION]: state => newState(state, ["orders", someOrderId, "fulfilled"], true)
```

...it's a bit less of a pain to write than the equivalent:

```
[SOME_ACTION]: state => ({
    ..state,
    orders: {
        ...state.orders,
        [someOrderId]: {
            ...state.orders[someOrderId],
            fulfilled: true
        }
    }
})
```

Example:

```js
const state = {
    isModified: false,
    orders: {
        "order1": {
            customer: "Joe Bloggs",
            fulfilled: false
        },
        "order2": {
            customer: "Jane Doe",
            fulfilled: false
        }
    },
    documentation: {
        foo: {},
        bar: {}
    }
};

const someOrderId = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "order1" : "order2";
const updated = newState(state, ["orders", someOrderId, "fulfilled"], true);
console.log(`Updated order '${someOrderId}':`);
console.log(updated);

function newState(state, path, value) {
    const result = {...state};
    const lastKey = path[path.length - 1];
    let obj = state;
    for (const key of path.slice(0, path.length - 1)) {
        obj = obj[key];
    }
    obj[lastKey] = value;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, especially for the utility example. Maybe you'll also help me clarify why so many project uses ImmutableJS library, does it provide a solution to handle my case with more "style"?

Comment: @jay_dtr - I haven't used it, but I suspect that it provides utilities like the one above.